# CSS selector of first input

Tags: html, css, selector

I want to select first input from this structure. I need only CSS selector, not jQuery.

```
<div class="sonata-ba-collapsed-fields">
    <div class="form-group" id="sonata-ba-field-container-s55e92cd5ce823_logoFile">
        <label class=" control-label">Logo File</label>

        <div class=" sonata-ba-field sonata-ba-field-standard-natural  ">
            <div class="vich-image">
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label class=" control-label" for="s55e92cd5ce823_logoFile_file">Logo File</label>

                    <div class="">
                        <input type="file" id="s55e92cd5ce823_logoFile_file" name="s55e92cd5ce823[logoFile][file]" class=" form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="sonata-ba-field-container-s55e92cd5ce823_iconFile">
        <label class=" control-label">Icon File</label>

        <div class=" sonata-ba-field sonata-ba-field-standard-natural  ">
            <div class="vich-image">
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label class=" control-label" for="s55e92cd5ce823_iconFile_file">Icon File </label>

                    <div class="">
                        <input type="file" id="s55e92cd5ce823_iconFile_file" name="s55e92cd5ce823[iconFile][file]" class=" form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm doing something like this http://jsfiddle.net/T4kAq/60/ but as you can see it selects both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS selector can be like this:

```css
div.sonata-ba-collapsed-fields > .form-group:nth-child(1) input {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/T4kAq/61/

Answer (score 0):

```
div.sonata-ba-collapsed-fields >  .form-group:first-child input:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

[**Jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/T4kAq/62/)